Is the Python Firebase Admin SDK able to handle concurrently uploading files to the Storage bucket?
I am trying to develop a Python FastAPI based web-server that will allow users to upload files to Firebase Storage, however my question is not related to the programming language or library being used, but regarding the usage of the firebase-admin-sdk.
As per the official documentation, we can initialize an async  firebase_admin.firestore_async module, but there is no way to get an async module for firebase_admin.storage.
Does this mean that I have to initialize a new firebase_admin.storage object for each incoming request per user?
If the above statement is true, then for concurrent users will each new object be responsible to upload a new (different) file?
